# vue js 2 way data binding not updating

Tags: vue.js

so i have a quick Vue JS question that seems very strange, i have the following

```
var home = new Vue({
 el: '#home',
 data:{
    title: 'welcome to the app'
 }
});
```

Which works fine, and title in my HTML gets updated fine...

now when i do this

```
home.$data.title = 'this is the new title'
```

the html

```
  <div class="app-topbar">{{title | uppercase}}</div>
```

Does not update, do i have to force an update to the data binding or something?

Thanks Sam

Answer (score 2):

For people still searching for this, the issue may be caused by caveats.

The best way to update data and force an event in the instance is to use Vue.set.

Follow the link : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Answer (score 2):

In last resort I've also used [Vue.forceUpdate()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate).

But indeed here looks like you should simply use `home.title`.

---

my checklist for this kind of problem:

- computed property ?
- `this.$set`
- beware of arrow functions and lodash
- with components: [.sync](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier)

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me. Just set `home.title`, like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/6x2v9y20/1/

Maybe you're trying to access home.title before the Vue item has been created?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `home.$data.title`, if your within your Vue instance you can simply alter the title value by using `this.title`.

Here's a quick fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/stefkosmo/6x2v9y20/

Comment: Hi sorry for not updating this sooner, what if you want to update the variable outside of the vue instance? So in a bit of JavaScript else where in the app ? Thank you

Comment: You can use home.title from the outside

Answer (score 0):

When you want to update data of an instance, the documented way is to set new data by `this.$set('title', 'this is the new title);`
when you do that, actually what framework does, is re-rendering your template and the html updates

http://vuejs.org/api/instance-methods.html#vm-\$set(_keypath\,*value*)